# How to save matches for items in list in onefile to another file

Tags: python

I came up with this code. And i don't get anything saved in ouput, It stays blank. Though code works and i see right matches printing in console.

```
for item in somelist:
    with open('eng.txt','r') as dic, open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
        for line in dic:
            if re.match(item, line):
                output.write(line)
                print line
```

I have tried another version:

```
for item in somelist:
    with open('eng.txt','r') as dic:
        for line in dic:
            if re.match(item, line):
                with open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
                    output.write(line)
                    print line
```

This way it only saves last line, but not all matches. How can i fix it?

Comment: note that matches tries to match from the begining of the line. Think you need `re.search`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this, open the output file in first step and then just write to the file if you want to.

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
    for item in final_list:
        with open('eng.txt','r') as dic:
            for line in dic:
                if re.match(item, line):
                    output.write(line)
                    print line
```

You created the file object *output* every time new in your second code snippet.

Comment: Indeed. And open('output.txt', 'a') as output in your snippets would work too ;)

Comment: surprisingly it works, and now i know what 'a' mode does.

Comment: "a" mode adds a string into the file